# Visualizing running services in Grafana

Tags: grafana

How to add query to visualize service running on Ubuntu using Grafana?

I tried to add conditions in where tag like `service=cron`, but it's not working.

```
FROM default processes WHERE host = ubuntu1604 AND service = cron
SELECT field(total)mean() GROUP BY time(10s)fill(null)F
FORMAT AS Time series
ALIAS BY Service
```

After adding service condition I'm not able to visualize the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you indicate exactly what the data source is? Is it InfluxDB? If so, you may need single quotes around what you are checking in where, such as:

```
host = 'ubuntu1604' and service = 'cron'
```